# Multi-process using curl, when must curl_global_init be called?

Tags: c, libcurl

As http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_global_init.html said, `curl_global_init()` is necessary but **this function is not thread safe.** As code below:

```
// main process
curl_global_init();   // 1 curl_global_init
pid = fork();
if (pid == 0) {
    // Child process
    curl_global_init();  // 2 curl_global_init
    // ... curl functions
} else {
    // parent process
    // ... curl functions 
}
```

Does child process need to call `curl_global_init` again? 
I think the child process copies the memory space from the parent process, and you do not need to call `curl_global_init` again. Is that right?

Comment: Your code isn't multithreaded, so why is the question about thread-safety?

Comment: i know. but do curl_global_init need to called twice after fork?

Comment: i can write curl_global_init(); and curl_global_cleanup(); every process if needed

Comment: "twice after `fork`"?? Your question only calls it *once* after `fork`...

Comment: include **main process** or the **parent process** before fork

Answer (score 1):

`curl_global_init` is to be called once. Remember that both fork creates a copy of the process at the time it was called, so it will replicate curl's state as well. Thus, there will be no need to call `curl_global_init` again in the child if the initialization was already done prior to the fork.

Answer (score -1):

But child process and parent process have difference memory space. I think no problem if call curl_global_init in child process

Comment: This looks like it should be a comment on an existing answer, not a new answer.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, there is  no need to call `curl_global_init()`